# How to access my files on 000webhost

Tags: ftp, wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

I've set up WordPress site at 000webhost(dot)com as pre-step to figure things out before paying for domain and hosting. It was fine for few days.

Thing is, available storage and inodes filled their limits without anyone accessing the site.

Problem is that i can't seem to see way to deal with (deleting logs, temp files, etc) aside from maybe deleting everything and start over.

I tried to:

- access files at files(dot)000webhost(dot)com, from old panel, from new panel and directly from browser = connection timeouts
- access via FTP  = connection timeouts.
- use word-press plugin to optimize WP like cache, resizing pictures, etc = fails probably due to lack of disk space
- backup / export site via WP plugins = fails probably due to lack of disk space

All above mentioned worked few days ago. So e.g. my login or ftp setting should be correct.

Webpage is still alive and i can access WP admin panel but can't even get plugin to optimize things to work, because there's 5% - 10% of available disk space or inodes left.
I can login to 000webhost dash-panel with no issue.

What else can i do to get to my files. At very least i wish to backup my page so i can move it elsewhere or reset it and load backup.

Answer (score 0):

```
VPN - Allows to access files at 000webhost
```

After days of trials and errors, I found out that connection to the server where 000webhost keeps files is possible only via VPN.

I have yet to understand why it was working at the beginning and why it now works only via random VPN connection.